Terrain and SpeedTree objects render correctly in Editor, but not in Build in both Legacy and URP
The game runs and shows perfectly in Editor, but when I make a build, terrain and some other objects become invisible. This happens the same in both Legacy (Standard) and URP.
I tried to create shader variants, and the "Always Included Shaders", added Standard shader, Terrain etc. to there, but still the same results.
The build has errors like:
"Shader Universal Render Pipeline/Nature/SpeedTree8, subshader 0, pass 1, stage all: variant _WINDQUALITY_NONE not found.

UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderPipelineManager:DoRenderLoop_Internal(RenderPipelineAsset, IntPtr, Object)


1- Editor View

2- Build View [Running On Bluestacks]

3- Runtime Errors in Build

4- Graphics Settings

Did you add the SpeedTree shader that's throwing the errors to your always included list?

@DMGregory
Firstly, the rendering issue isn't only with Terrain, but also a vehicle being shown as in editor which is Non-Terrain Object and isn't being shown in the build.
And I am using URP shader for tree. And in the "Always Include Shaders", I don't see the URP version of SpeedTree shader, it only shows "Nature/SpeedTree" not that of URP. And yes I added that, and still getting same error and rendering issue.
